# A simple BSON indenter / compacter

Tags: javascript, parsing, json

[BSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) is an extended JSON format. For example these documents are valid BSON documents, but invalid JSON documents:

**prettified documents:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "k": 10,
    "dt": ISODate("2018-10-10")
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),
    "k": {
      "field1": "someVal",
      "field2": 12.2323242
    }
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    k: 7
  }
]
```

**compacted documents**

```
[{"_id":ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),"k":10,"dt":ISODate("2018-10-10")},{"_id":ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001"),"k":{"field1":"someVal","field2":12.2323242}},{_id:ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),k:7}]
```

I recently needed a tool to compact or prettify BSON documents. After several attempts with javascript formatter (beautifyjs, prettifier ...) I ended up implementing my own solution.

---

**Important**:

the goal of this code is **not** to check if a document has a valid BSON syntax, but only to prettify/compact a BSON document. Hence, it assumes that the `src` is valid BSON

Here is my solution:

```
const compactMode = 0
const indentMode = 1


function indent(src) {
    return write(src, indentMode)
}

function compact(src) {
    return write(src, compactMode)
}

function write(src, mode) {

    var result = ""
    var needIndent = false
    var inValue = false
    var depth = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
        c = src.charAt(i)

        if (c === " " && !inValue || c === "\n") {
            continue
        }

        if (needIndent && c !== "]" && c !== "}") {
            needIndent = false
            depth++
            result += newline(mode, depth)
        }

        switch (c) {
            case "{":
            case "[":
                needIndent = true
                result += c
                break
            case ",":
                result += c
                result += newline(mode, depth)
                break
            case ":":
                result += c
                if (mode === indentMode && !inValue) {
                    result += " "
                } 
                break
            case "}":
            case "]":
                if (needIndent) {
                    needIndent = false
                } else {
                    depth--
                    result += newline(mode, depth)
                }
                result += c
                break
            case "\"":
            case "'": // if we get a `'`, replace it with `"`
                inValue = !inValue
                result += "\""
                break
            default:
                result += c
        }
    }
    return result
}

function newline(mode, depth) {
    if (mode === compactMode) {
        return ""
    }
    var line = "\n"
    for (var i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
        line += "  "
    }
    return line
}
```

How can I improve this ?

Comment: Hi there Felix, I have rolled back your recent edits. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @202_accepted thanks for the link, didn't knew that

Comment: That's perfectly OK. That's why people like me pop in and let you know, so that you don't think we're being mean or anything, and you have that information for the next question/answer. :) I hope you receive more reviews, and get some good feedback.

Answer (score 3):

> the goal of this code is not to check if a document has a valid BSON syntax

But that's the first requirement of a formatter, *understanding the syntax*. For any formatter to work, it must understand the structure of the input. For instance, if I stick a `{` inside some random string, how would `case "{":` tell it apart from a structural `{`?

So in some form, your parser, no matter how simple, would need to know about *some* of these rules. You don't need to build a robust parser, you just need to know where the current character is based characters already encountered.

You can use JSON's [flow diagrams](https://www.json.org/) as a guide to know when it's possible to encounter such characters. You just need to extend it for BSON. Also, here's [a simple JS comment remover](https://j11y.io/javascript/removing-comments-in-javascript/) which removes comments from JS *without having to understand the entire JS syntax*. In a gist, it went through the string, checking the current character against the current state (i.e. am I in a string, a regexp, comment, etc.) then modifying the code accordingly as it went through.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but actually I make sure that the input is correct BSON in another part of the code, see my edit